# Участие ... и выдача сертификата ... бесплатное/бесплатные

Tags: согласование

> 1.Участие в мастер-классе и выдача сертификата участника бесплатные.

или

> 2.Участие в мастер-классе и выдача сертификата участника бесплатное.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: ***Участие в мастер-классе и выдача сертификата участника бесплатные***.

Участие в мастер-классе бесплатное. Выдача  сертификата участника бесплатная.

**Но!** Участие в мастер-классе и выдача сертификата участника ***бесплатные***.

Answer (score 1):

В рекламе весьма приветствуется краткость: **Участие** в мастер-классе и выдача сертификата участника **бесплатно**. К тому же, главное здесь — знание, что может обеспечить участие, а не бонусы.